# Using FOR loop to copy code between to labels in batch file

Tags: for-loop, command-line, windows-7, copy, batch-processing

Ok so I write in batch files a lot. A while back I asked a question `user:cmd` on how to copy one part of a running batch file into a new batch file,
Well it works if your going to use it one time in a batch file. My goal is to create multiple large batch files from within a single setup batch. What happens is if they choose to install, then the batch file runs the following.

```
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color e
::Start of embedded code


set Begin=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^:EMBEDDED_CODE" "%~F0"') do (
if not defined Begin (
set Begin=%%a
) else (
  set End=%%a
)
)
::*****************************************************************************
(for /F "skip=%Begin% tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /N /V "" "%~F0"') do (
   if %%a equ %End% goto :Build-file2
   echo(%%b
)) > file1.bat & goto :Build-file2
)

goto :Build-file2

:EMBEDDED_CODE Begin

CODE TO PUT INTO "file1.bat"

:EMBEDDED_CODE End


:Build-file2

cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color e
::Start of embedded code


set Begin=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^:EMBEDDED_CODE" "%~F0"') do (
if not defined Begin (
set Begin=%%a
) else (
  set End=%%a
)
)
::*****************************************************************************
(for /F "skip=%Begin% tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /N /V "" "%~F0"') do (
   if %%a equ %End% goto :EOF
   echo(%%b
)) > file2.bat & goto :EOF
)

goto :EOF

:EMBEDDED_CODE Begin

CODE TO PUT INTO "file2.bat"

:EMBEDDED_CODE End
```

The problem that is occurring is instead of it just copying the code between labels `EMBEDDED_CODE Begin` and `EMBEDDED_CODE End` in the first `FOR` loop it copies from `EMBEDDED_CODE Begin` down to the very bottom of the script puts it in the file I want and then goes to the next `FOR` loop which repeats the process with different code between the to labels. so `file1.bat` and `file2.bat` both contain the exact same code but with the desired file names of `file1.bat` AND `file2.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect anything different than the results you are getting? The FINDSTR will search the entire file, so `Begin` is set to the first occurrence of `:EMBEDDED_CODE` in the first block of code, and `End` is set to the last occurrence in the last block of code (last value set wins). You replicate the code, so of course you get the same faulty result two times.

Simply change the labels in your second block of code, perhaps `:EMBEDDED_CODE2`, and adjust your 2nd FINDSTR accordingly. All should work then.

I often use a slightly different approach that minimizes the amount of file reading. Simply modify all lines from a given embedded block of code with the same unique prefix. Then FINDSTR can directly output the desired lines, and a FOR /F is used to strip off the prefix. You just need the prefix to end with a character that never matches the beginning of your code.

You should be careful about enabling delayed expansion when reading a file with FOR /F. Your embedded code will be corrupted if it contains `!` and delayed expansion is enabled. (unless the `!` is escaped, but that can be a pain)

```
@echo off

for %%C in (1 2) do (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=}" %%A in ('findstr /bl ":%%C}" "%~f0"') do echo(%%B
)>file%%C.bat

:1}Your first code block goes here
:1}
:1}  Blank lines and indents are preserved
:1}And so are exclamation points!

:2}And here is your second code block
:2}...

echo file1.bat
echo ---------
type file1.bat
echo(
echo(
echo file2.bat
echo ---------
type file2.bat
```

Comment: I did try that as well without success but I have not yet tried the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

This will almost do what you need.

This code needs to read twice the input file, first to locate the range of lines to process (findstr line numbering), and second to extract them. In second loop findstr numbering is used again to avoid `for /f` to compress blank lines and alter line numbering.

On the other hand, the problem with special characters inside extacted text is handled, enabling and disabling delayed expansion as needed.

Maybe not the best performance, but it seems to work. Adapt as needed.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    call :extractEmbedded "Section1" extracted.txt
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        cls
        type extracted.txt
    )

    exit /b

:extractEmbedded id outputFile
    rem prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem asume failure on execution
    set "_return=1"

    rem find embedded zone in current file
    set "_start="
    set "_end="
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%l in ('findstr /n /b /c:":EMBEDDED %~1" "%~f0"') do (
        if not defined _start ( set "_start=%%l" ) else ( set "_end=%%l" )
    )

    rem adjust lines to process
    set /a "_start+=0"
    set /a "_end-=1"

    rem if nothing found, task done
    if %_start% GEQ %_end% goto endExtractEmbedded

    rem prepare file extraction
    if "%_start%"=="0" (set "_skip=" ) else ( set "_skip=skip^=%_start%" )

    rem extract proper area of file to output file
    (for /f tokens^=^*^ %_skip%^ eol^= %%l in ('findstr /n "^" "%~f0"') do if !_start! LSS !_end! (
        setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
        set "_line=%%l"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!_line:*:=!
        endlocal & endlocal 
        set /a "_start+=1"
    ))>"%~2" 

    rem everything ok
    set "_return=0"

:endExtractEmbedded
    rem exit with errorlevel
    endlocal & exit /b %_return%



:EMBEDDED Section1

    This is a section; of embedded!!! code
    that needs to be extracted to generate
    a new file to be processed.
    TEST: !""$%&/()=?¿^*[];,:-\|

:EMBEDDED Section1
```